# Hive job details through Java program

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I have Hive queries which are fired through my Java program. Is there is a way to get JOB details like ID, Name, Job Submit time for that particular Hive query. I know these details are found at job tracker. Can I get Job details which are specific to my Hive query through a Java program?